# Rss Feed Reader "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, integration, apexrest

While using XML DOM functionality in apex to read Rss Feed from external website I am facing the `"Attempt to de-reference a null object"`. As I am new to salesforce I am not understanding where I am making mistake.

Added URL `"http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/topstories"`in Remote Site Settings

Here is my code :

Class :

```
public class RSS1 {

public class channel {
    public String title {get;set;}
    public String link {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String author {get;set;}
    public String category {get;set;}
    public String copyright {get;set;}
    public String docs {get;set;}
    public RSS.image image {get;set;}
    public list<RSS.item> items {get;set;}
    public channel() {
        items = new list<RSS.item>();
    }
}

public class image {
    public String url {get;set;}
    public String title {get;set;}
    public String link {get;set;}
}

public class item {
    public String title {get;set;}
    public String guid {get;set;}
    public String link {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String pubDate {get;set;}
    public String source {get;set;}
    public Date getPublishedDate() {
        Date result = (pubDate != null) ? Date.valueOf(pubDate.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z','')) : null;
        return result;
    }
    public DateTime getPublishedDateTime() {
        DateTime result = (pubDate != null) ? DateTime.valueOf(pubDate.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z','')) : null;
        return result;
    }
}

public static RSS.channel getRSSData(string feedURL) {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(feedURL);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
    Http h = new Http();

   /* if (!Test.isRunningTest()){ 
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        doc = res.getBodyDocument();
    } else {
        String xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"><channel><title>salesforce.com - Bing News</title><link>http://www.bing.com/news</link><description>Search Results for salesforce.com at Bing.com</description><category>News</category><os:totalResults>3370</os:totalResults><os:startIndex>0</os:startIndex><os:itemsPerPage>10</os:itemsPerPage><os:Query role="request" searchTerms="salesforce.com" /><copyright>These XML results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner or for any purpose other than rendering Bing results within an RSS aggregator for your personal, non-commercial use. Any other use requires written permission from Microsoft Corporation. By using these results in any manner whatsoever, you agree to be bound by the foregoing restrictions.</copyright><image><url>http://www.bing.com/s/a/rsslogo.gif</url><title>Bing</title><link>http://www.bing.com/news</link></image><docs>http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification</docs><item><title>Salesforce.com Makes Friends With CIOs - Information Week</title><guid>http://informationweek.com/news/cloud-computing/software/232602782</guid><link>http://informationweek.com/news/cloud-computing/software/232602782</link><description>Parade of CIOs at CloudForce shows how social networking inroads are making Salesforce.com a larger part of the IT infrastructure. Salesforce.com isn&apos;t just for sales forces anymore. Its Chatter app has opened a social networking avenue into the enterprise ...</description><pubDate>2012-03-19T15:21:47Z</pubDate><source>Information Week</source></item></channel></rss>';
        doc.load(xmlString);
    }*/

    Dom.XMLNode rss = doc.getRootElement();
    //first child element of rss feed is always channel
    Dom.XMLNode channel = rss.getChildElements()[0];

    RSS.channel result = new RSS.channel();

    list<RSS.item> rssItems = new list<RSS.item>();

    //for each node inside channel
    for(Dom.XMLNode elements : channel.getChildElements()) {
        if('title' == elements.getName()) {
            result.title = elements.getText();
        }
        if('link' == elements.getName()) {
            result.link = elements.getText();
        }
        if('description' == elements.getName()) {
            result.description = elements.getText();
        }
        if('category' == elements.getName()) {
            result.category = elements.getText();
        }
        if('copyright' == elements.getName()) {
            result.copyright = elements.getText();
        }
        if('docs' == elements.getName()) {
            result.docs = elements.getText();
        }
        if('image' == elements.getName()) {
            RSS.image img = new RSS.image();
            //for each node inside image
            for(Dom.XMLNode xmlImage : elements.getChildElements()) {
                if('url' == xmlImage.getName()) {
                    img.url = xmlImage.getText();
                }
                if('title' == xmlImage.getName()) {
                    img.title = xmlImage.getText();
                }
                if('link' == xmlImage.getName()) {
                    img.link = xmlImage.getText();
                }
            }
            result.image = img;
        }

        if('item' == elements.getName()) {
            RSS.item rssItem = new RSS.item();
            //for each node inside item
            for(Dom.XMLNode xmlItem : elements.getChildElements()) {
                if('title' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.title = xmlItem.getText();
                }
                if('guid' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.guid = xmlItem.getText();
                }
                if('link' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.link = xmlItem.getText();
                }
                if('description' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.description = xmlItem.getText();
                }
                if('pubDate' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.pubDate = xmlItem.getText();
                }
                if('source' == xmlItem.getName()) {
                    rssItem.source = xmlItem.getText();
                }
            }
            //for each item, add to rssItem list
            rssItems.add(rssItem);
        }

    }
    //finish RSS.channel object by adding the list of all rss items
    result.items = rssItems;

    return result;

}

 /* static testMethod void RSSTest() {
    RSS.channel chan = RSS.getRSSData('test');
    Date pDate = chan.items[0].getPublishedDate();
    DateTime pDateTime = chan.items[0].getPublishedDateTime();
 } */

 }
```

VF Page :

```
    <apex:page controller="RSSNewsReader1" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false">

<apex:pageBlock id="rssBlock" tabStyle="Lead">

    <apex:form style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <span>Bing News Query (Enter a Topic): </span>
        <apex:inputText value="{!rssQuery}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Search Bing News" reRender="rssBlock" status="searchStatus" />
        <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus" startStyleClass="ajax-loader" />
    </apex:form>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Channel" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="title" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.title}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="link" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.link}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="description" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.description}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="category" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.category}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="docs" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.docs}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="copyright" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.copyright}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Image" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="title" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.image.title}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="url" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.image.url}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="link" />
            <apex:outputText value="{!RSSFeed.image.link}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="url image" />
            <apex:image value="{!RSSFeed.image.url}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Items" columns="1">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RSSFeed.items}" var="i">
            <apex:column headerValue="title">
                <apex:outputLink value="{!i.link}" target="_blank">{!i.title}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="description" value="{!i.description}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="pubDate" style="width: 140px;">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss a}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!i.PublishedDateTime}" />
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="source" value="{!i.source}" style="width: 140px;" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class RSSNewsReader1 {

    public String rssQuery {get;set;}
    private String rssURL {get;set;}

    public RSSNewsReader1() {

        rssURL = 'http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/topstories';


    }

    public RSS.channel getRSSFeed() {
        return RSS1.getRSSData(rssURL);
    }



}
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you commented too much.

Instead of this:

```
  /* if (!Test.isRunningTest()){ 
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        doc = res.getBodyDocument();
    } else {
        String xmlString = '<?xml....';
        doc.load(xmlString);
    }*/
```

Do This :

```
 /* if (!Test.isRunningTest()){  */
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        doc = res.getBodyDocument();
 /*       
   } else {
        String xmlString = '<?xml....';
        doc.load(xmlString);   
    }*/
```

Comment: YW, Sal. Please mark the solution as accepted so others can benefit!

Comment: Rss feed items are displaying empty is anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: You're doing some XML parsing... I have no way of knowing if that is correct or not. I suggest opening a new question so others can pitch in